# plot t distribution from t test?

Tags: r

Is it possible to make a t distribution plot for a two sample t test, a plot as:
[image]
What I mean is after doing a t test I would like to have a visualisation in the form of the above picture.

```
> A
[1] -0.2657783 -0.1655625 -0.3254466
> B
[1] -2.824755 -2.889368
> t.test(A,B)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  A and B
t = 45.906, df = 2.9989, p-value = 2.283e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.424183 2.785415
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
-0.2522625 -2.8570614
```

Someone posted an answer and unfortuanately delted it, however this brought me to this code (which is **not** working). I have to add  `a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'` However I don't understand what I have to put in the x variabele?

```
# generate data
a <- rnorm(mean(A), sd(A),1000)
b <- rnorm(mean(B), sd(B),1000)

# plot data
curve(dnorm(x, mean(A), sd(A)), from=-4, to=1, ylab="f(x)")
curve(dnorm(x, mean(B), sd(B)), from=-4, to=1, add=TRUE, col="red")

# add vertical lines
abline(v=c(mean(A), mean(B)), col=c("black", "red"))
```

Comment: What exactly is your "above" picture supposed to be showing? It has no labels so we'd just be guessing as to what it represents.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out I edited my question @Dason

Comment: That kinda looks like what I'm trying to do however I would prefer "curve" and I don't want to compare between "sizes of n" in my plot but I want to compare two different dataset @DarshanBaral

Comment: I don't get the error "a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'" when running that code. Your parameters to `rnorm` are in the wrong order. I assume you mean `a <- rnorm(1000, mean(A), sd(A))` so maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using just base curve, assuming df=25:

```
x  <- function(x) dt(x, df=25)
y  <- function(x) dt(x + 0.2, df=25) # shift "mean"

curve(x, -3, 3, ylab="dt(df=25)", col="blue" )
curve(y, -3, 3,  col="red", add = TRUE)
```